# Mouse events on vertex of JUNG graph

Tags: java, mouseevent, jung2

I have constructed graphs with JUNG but I'm not sure how to add mouse action listeners to the vertices of the graph.

Below is a sample section of my code that I think is the most relevant for the problem.

```
layout = new FRLayout2<GraphNode, GraphEdge>(graph);
visualizationViewer = new VisualizationViewer<GraphNode, GraphEdge>(layout, new Dimension(1000, 700));

visualizationViewer.getModel().getRelaxer().setSleepTime(500);
visualizationViewer.setGraphMouse(new DefaultModalGraphMouse<GraphNode, String>());
        visualizationViewer.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Renderer.VertexLabel.Position.AUTO);
visualizationViewer.setForeground(Color.black);
```

In particular, I want to detect single and double clicks on the vertices of a graph and act on them.

Note: I have seen a couple of old SO links, but none of the answers seem to be helping me. If someone can just give me the pseudocode or point me to the right direction, it would be really helpful.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't give you the information you need, please feel free to comment and I will try to better suit it to your needs. I tried to design my answer generally so there is immediately usable code and a full example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a full example will serve you and others better than just modifying your code. The relevant part here is, assuming you already have a `VisualizationViewer`, to use this snippet:

```
visualizationViewer.addGraphMouseListener(new GraphMouseListener() {...});
```

Besides handling click events, this also allows you to add press and release events.

This standalone class creates a simple graph and -- when a vertex is clicked on -- prints on stdout what vertex was clicked.

```java
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.Layout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph; 
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.control.GraphMouseListener;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.decorators.ToStringLabeller;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class METest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create a test graph
        Graph graph = new SparseGraph<String, String>();
        graph.addVertex("a");
        graph.addVertex("b");
        graph.addVertex("c");
        graph.addVertex("d");
        graph.addEdge("a->b", "a", "b");
        graph.addEdge("a->c", "a", "c");
        graph.addEdge("b->c", "b", "c");
        graph.addEdge("c->d", "c", "d");
        //Metrics
        visualize(graph);
    }

    public static void visualize(Graph graph) {
        //Layout graph.
        Layout layout = new CircleLayout(graph);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500)); // sets the initial size of the space
        VisualizationViewer server = new VisualizationViewer(layout);
        server.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        //Here you add the listener
        server.addGraphMouseListener(new GraphMouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void graphClicked(Object v, MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && me.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Double clicked "+ v);
                }
                me.consume();
            }

            @Override
            public void graphPressed(Object v, MouseEvent me) {
            }

            @Override
            public void graphReleased(Object v, MouseEvent me) {
            }
        });
        //Show the frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Graph View");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(server);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I shall give this a try and get back to you in case I need any more clarifications!

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the code to account for double click detection.

Comment: @Uli Köhler, Brilliant answer! Is it also possible to get Edge object as well? Now I only get Vertex object, which is really great for now.